# Windows 7 hangs on bootup - Culprit appears to be Network Location Awareness

Tags: windows-7, windows-service

We just finished our deployment of Windows 7 a few weeks ago. Everything ran great for a while. This week an issue started popping up. Random computers will hang on "Please Wait" during bootup. We can leave them for days and they will stay there. If we disable the Network Location Awareness service, they bootup just fine. Then we re-enable it and everything runs smooth (most of the time). A couple of machines experience the issue again on their next reboot. Other machines have had the issue once and then seemed fine after. All machines are the same Dell models (7010) and were imaged with the same image. So far, the only solution I've found online is to disable that service and then re-enable it. That works as a band-aid, but does anybody have a permanent solution for this?

Comment: How did you image these? One suggestion I have (based on issues I've seen with imaged machines) is to uninstall the NIC in Device Manager and let Windows reinstall it.

Comment: We imaged them with WDS. The particular network card isn't recognized by Windows, so we included network drivers with the image.